# Running multiple files on the Judge API

Tags: go, judge-api

I am trying to compile multiple files with the Judge API. I have two GO files, main.go and main_test.go. Additionally, I have the mod file and one `run.sh` script. I the zip files and base64 it and send the result to `additional_files` as stated in the [documentation](https://ce.judge0.com/#submissions-submission-post).

The contents of my `run.sh` file looks like

```
go run -v
```

Sadly I get

```
run.sh: line 1: go: command not found
```

Has anyone ran multiple GO files using the Judge API?

Comment: It's been a while but did you figure this out? I need to do this with Java.